Calling Cloud Function in a Firebase Project from another Function in another project
I have two distinct Firebase projects, let's call them ProjectA and ProjectB. In ProjectA I have a Cloud Function that gets called from my app, let's call it askFunction. This function makes a request to a Cloud Function in ProjectB, let's call it checkFunction. These are Cloud Run functions.
As long as checkFunction has the Cloud Run Invoker role granted to allUsers it is public and everything works fine, but anyone could call checkFunction without any restriction, so I would like for checkFunction to be callable only by ProjectA (better if it could be callable only by ProjectA's askFunction, but only by ProjectA could suffice) or by a handful of specific Firebase projects. However, it seems like I'm making some mistake in the configuration or in the code, as my requests gets rejected.
In ProjectB I have removed allUsers from the Cloud Run Invoker role both in the Cloud Run console and in the IAM console, and granted the Cloud Run Invoker role to ProjectA's service account (firebase-adminsdk-aaaaa@projecta.iam.gserviceaccount.com) to checkFunction, but every time I call askFunction its request gets rejected with error 403 or 401, based on the implementation that I am trying. From checkFunction's log I always get the WARNING that the request was not authorized or was not authenticated, even if I've put the service account as a Cloud Run Invoker (and even a Cloud Function Invoker, to be sure).
I've tried using GoogleAuth to get the ID token and send the request using its headers because the documentation says that if I have multiple services talking to each other I should use the ID token to authenticate the request if the function is not publicly available, and in this case they are both Google Cloud services, but the result remains the same.
I've looked around but I haven't found anything on this specific scenario.
These are the mockups of the two functions that I'm using:
ProjectA's askFunction
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

exports.askFunction = onCall(async (request) => {
  const param = request.data.param;
  try {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const headers = await client.getRequestHeaders();
    const url = `https://REGION-PROJECTB.cloudfunctions.net/checkFunction?param=${param}`;

    const response = await client.request({ url, headers });

    return { code: 200, message: "OK", ...response.data };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      code: error.response ? error.response.status : 500,
      message: "Error calling checkFunction",
    };
  }
});

ProjectB's checkFunction
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

exports.checkFunction = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // It doesn't matter as this function doesn't get called
  try {
    
    // Perform the check
    
    return res.status(200).send({
      check: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

I've also tried using Axios to perform the request with the same result, but since it seems that I have to use GoogleAuth for the authentication I could perform the request directly from there.
It seems as if the request is not coming from ProjectA's service account, but from google-api-nodejs-client and so ProjectB doesn't allow it, but I could be wrong.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Have you tried the code sample provided in the service-to-service documentation? I'm unsure what GCP expects for this when targeting GCF, but it probably needs an audience of https://REGION-PROJECTB.cloudfunctions.net/, https://REGION-PROJECTB.run.app/ or https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.
